# How to save in database value with vue js?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

This calendar is made with vuejs.

[image: calendar]

But the problem I have, After selecting the date, it does not store any value in the database.

I want to store a vuejs component in a database. Is there some sort of serialization procedure/package that I can use to serialize vuejs components?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <input type="hidden" id="id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="edit_start_date">تاریخ شروع به كار</label>
                <date-picker type="date" id="edit_start_date" name="start_date"></date-picker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="edit_end_date">تاریخ خاتمه كار</label>
                <date-picker type="date" id="edit_end_date" name="end_date"></date-picker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

script

```
$(document).on('click', '#jobEdit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'/job/'+id+'/edit',
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#id').val(data.job.id);
            $('#edit_employment_type').val(data.job.employment_type);
            $('#edit_job_type').val(data.job.job_type);
            $('#edit_history').val(data.job.history);
            $('#edit_post_title').val(data.job.post_title);
            $('#edit_state_id').val(data.job.state_id);
            $('#edit_city_id').val(data.job.city_id);
            $('#edit_start_date').val(data.job.start_date);
            $('#edit_end_date').val(data.job.end_date);
        },
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#jobUpdate', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var data = {
        'employment_type' : $('#edit_employment_type').val(),
        'job_type' : $('#edit_job_type').val(),
        'history' : $('#edit_history').val(),
        'post_title' : $('#edit_post_title').val(),
        'state_id' : $('#edit_state_id').val(),
        'city_id' : $('#edit_city_id').val(),
        'start_date' : $('#edit_start_date').val(),
        'end_date' : $('#edit_end_date').val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/job/'+id,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#jobModal').modal('hide');
            showJobs();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery?

Comment: Because, this project was already with jQuery, I only added this calendar.

Comment: I suggest that, if you don't want to get rid of JQuery in this, that you use a date picker component made for JQuery (there are many) instead of injecting Vue.js for that. Vue and JQuery are very different species and they are not designed to work well together.

Comment: I only added this calendar. This project was already with jQuery,